# Display CSV Contents in a Table using Views/Template

Tags: django, csv, django-templates, django-views

I am creating a site where users can upload a csv file, and am currently working on a page where users can view the contents of the file without downloading it. To do this I am reading the csv in views like so:

```
def source_details(request, source_id):
    context_dict = {}

    # Get a specific object
    data_source = Source.objects.get(id=source_id)
    context_dict['data_source'] = data_source

    # Open the csv and print it to terminal
    with open(MEDIA_ROOT+data_source.sample, newline='') as csvfile:
        spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
        for row in spamreader:
            print(', '.join(row))


    return render(request, 'data/source-details.html', context_dict)
```

As you can see so far I have no trouble opening the uploaded csv file and printing it to the terminal, however I would like to display it in the browser as a table. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make a list of lists like:

```
csv_preform = [[row1],[row2],[row3]]
```

and then pass it to context and loop it in template like table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Test1</th>
    <th>Test2</th>
         ...
</tr>

{% for row in csv_preform %}
<tr>
    {% for sub_row in row %}
        <td>{{sub_row}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```